# Parallel ForEach not awaiting for HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

In the code below (a fairly simple one just for demonstration), my `finally` clause gets executed when awaiting for the `HttpClient` to finish. So the output is something like:

> Done
>
> StatusCode: 200,...

When I was expecting it to be:

> StatusCode: 200,...
>
> Done

```
  class Program
        {
            private static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                var numbers = new List<int> {1};
                try
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            Parallel.ForEach(numbers, async (number) => { await Do1(); });
                        });
                }
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Done");
                }
    
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            private static async Task Do1()
            {
                using (var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
            private static async Task Do2()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Doing" + await Multiply(i));
                }
            }
    
            private static async Task<int> Multiply(int number)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(number * number);
            }
        }
```

If I replace my Main method to use the `Do2` method then everything works as expected with the following output ("Done" gets printed at the very end):

> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> Doing100
>
> Done

So why is the `HttpClient` not working as I am expecting it to work?
Something that I'd like to mention is that I would like to use the Parallel.ForEach instead of the Task.WhenAll function.

Comment: `Parallel.Foreach` only accepts an action, which means when you give it async delegate you end up with an unawaitable async void and nothing waits for that async void delegate to complete before moving on.

Comment: Is your goal to execute Do1() in parallel?

Comment: JSteward, As long as I'm concerned, the Parallel.ForEach blocks the current thread until all the threads it creates finish before moving forward. The Do1 thread hasn't finished yet, so why is it moving forward?

Comment: because you didn't it to wait ... he did wrote it already *nothing waits for that async void delegate*

Comment: Magnus, I want to use the Do1() in parallel, but when using the httpclient it doesn't work. If I replace Do1() with Do2(), everything works as I expect.

Comment: Selvin, I'm not sure I understand. Can you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` does not return a task that you can await.

Comment: in fact `Do1` stop blocking when you use `await` from this point the Thread which call `Do1` is free to run other code ... and `Do2` has no `await` so it's not real aync call (you prolly have warning)

Comment: Magnus, why does Do2 work differently? In Do2 I'm awaiting too and the Finally doesn't get executed until everything finishes.

Comment: @ShakHam you're using the wrong class. `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for data parallelism, not concurrent calls. It doesn't support asynchronous methods *precisely* because it's not meant for concurrent/asynchronous work. It has no overloads that accept a `Func<T,Task>`. Your calls are essentially `async void` calls that nobody awaits

Comment: BTW there are a *lot* of duplicate questions, at least 3 of them answered by me, that explain this, explaining the *correct* classes for this job and including examples using eg ActionBlock or Channels

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos what are your thoughts regarding Gabriel Luci suggestion? To use https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/34233

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, can you add a link to your answers, please? I'm not that familiar with ActionBlock or Channels

Comment: I appreciate all of your help guys! I saw the answers that are related to this.

Comment: I was typing up an answer to clarify why `Do2` works differently, but the question got closed. The short answer is that it's not doing anything asynchronous. If `await` sees a completed `Task`, then execution continues synchronously. And your `Multiply` method always returns a completed `Task`.

Comment: Gabriel Luci, what are your suggestions on the DOP parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by "DOP parameter"?

Comment: @GabrielLuci DOP = Degree Of Parallelism